# Why does this regex match only once?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the Chinese Weibo username. So I use this code:

```
def atExtractor(sentence):
    return re.findall("@.*\\s", sentence, re.I)
```

And then I extract this sentence:

```
atExtractor(u"@中国联通网上营业厅 @北京地铁 北京地铁10号线，从惠新西街南口到海淀黄庄")
```

It get:

```
[u'@中国联通网上营业厅 @北京地铁 ']
```

Why the regex only get one match but not two? And the same problem happens when I want to extract hashtag:

```
 def activityExtractor(sentence):
        return re.findall("#.*#", sentence, re.I)
 activityExtractor(u"#中国联通网上营业厅# #北京地铁# 北京地铁10号线")
```

It get:

```
[u'#中国联通网上营业厅# #北京地铁# ']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your pattern is greedy.

```
re.findall("@.*?(?=\\s)", sentence, re.I)
```

or

```
re.findall(r"@\S*", sentence, re.I)
```

`\S*` should match zero or more non-space characters.